# Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Reorder' in '/Users/user/Documents/my portfolio/web-site-1/src/components'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from '../assets/Logo.svg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../styles/Navbar.css';
import {ReorderIcon} from '@mui/icons-material/Reorder';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <div className="navLogo">
                <Link to="/"><img src={Logo} /></Link>
            </div>
            <div className="rightMenu">
            <Link className="link"  to="products">products</Link>
            <Link className="link"  to="story">story</Link>
            <Link className="link"  to="manufactoring">manufactoring</Link>
            <Link className="link" to="packaging">packaging</Link>
            </div>
            <button>
            <ReorderIcon />
            </button>
        </div>
    );
} 

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Импорт иконки можно посмотреть [здесь](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=Reorder&selected=Reorder):

```
import ReorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Reorder';
```

Comment: Изначально импорт был именно таким "import ReorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Reorder';", ошибка остается такой же

Comment: @KasperPirs значит там пусто, если у вас версия материал юай старая, то может быть этот путь import ReorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Reorder';

Либо причина в чем то еще, загляните в папку node_modules

Comment: Проверил модули, странная штука они не установились, я снова установил он пишет что файлы добавлены но по факту ничего нет

Comment: @KasperPirs ну тогда это уже вопрос совсем другой, в догадки тут можно играть бесконечно

Answer (score 0):

ползуй так

```
import {Reorder} from "@mui/icons-material";
<Reorder> </Reorder>
```